# How to perform the p.adjust in R?

Tags: r

I have a data frame with `p.value`s and I want to adjust the `p.values`. I used this commad:

```
Padjust = p.adjust(pvalues, "fdr")
```

`pvalues` is my data frame with missing values and `fdr` is the method that I wish to use. However, I´m getting the following error:

```
Error in p.adjust(pvalues, "fdr") : 
 (list) object cannot be coerced to type 'double
```

Comment: The first argument of `p.adjust` is a vector of p values, not a dataframe...

Comment: If your data.frame contains all the p.values, maybe you want to use sapply()? `sapply(pvalues, p.adjust, method="fdr")`

Answer (score 3):

The first argument of `p.adjust` should be a vector, see

```
?p.adjust
```

In your specific case, you need to select the values from your data frame and pass them to the function, so something like:

```
p.adjust(pvalues$p.values, "fdr")
```

if the column name was `p.values`. You could then add the adjusted p-values to your data frame via:

```
pvalues$adjust = p.adjust(pvalues$p.values, "fdr")
```